# Missing asset message when building the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

I am in the process of creating a 3d game and therefore have been bringing in .fbx files for the 3d models without any issues so far. However, one of my .fbx files is now creating a missing asset error message when building. The error message is:

*Error  1   Missing asset "C:\Users\RICHARD\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Basketball\Basketball\BasketballContent". C:\Users\RICHARD\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Basketball\Basketball\BasketballContent\court.fbx    Basketball*

The .fbx file has been exported to include the textures required for the model. Also I was able to successfully use the .fbx file earlier without the missing asset message appearing and see the model in my xna game.

I am not sure what I could have done to cause this message as I have changed the code in the solution nor anything major on the model.

The other 3d models are unaffected. I have tried renaming the file without success. I have also tried to load the original file without success. I have also been cleaning the project and rebuilding with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting the question I have discovered an issue with the model that I was using that causing a bad export from 3ds max. It is now fixed and I am able to build the project.